# A trouble understanding a lemma in the article 'A natural model of the multiverse axioms'.

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

In the article '[A natural model of the multiverse axioms](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ndjfl/1285765800)' by Gitman and Hamkins, they give the following lemma:

> **Lemma 5.** If ZFC is consistent, then there are $2^{ℵ_0}$ many pairwise nonisomorphic countable computably saturated models of ZFC. Every real is in the standard system of such a model.

Here I understand a real a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, but then, not every real can be coded by a set in a countable model $M$, since two sets which codes different reals should be different. I also have a trouble to understand the proof of this article. It says

> (...) For any real $x$, one can ensure that the type expressing that $x$ is coded is realized.

but the type 
$$ p(y) = \{\ulcorner y\subset \omega\urcorner  \}\cup \{\ulcorner S^n0\in y\urcorner  : n\in x\} \cup \{\ulcorner S^n0\notin y\urcorner  : n\notin x\},$$
which says $y$ codes $x$, is not necessarily computable unless $x$ is computable. I feel there is a misunderstanding somewhere, and I can't find what makes a trouble. I would appropriate someone's help.

Comment: Every real occurs in some such model (of which their are $2^{\aleph_{0}}$-many). It doesn't say that there is a model containing the code of every real.

Comment: @StefanMesken Thank you!